# how can I verify if an String is already in a hashtable? java

Tags: java, arraylist, hashtable

I have the following case: I'm trying to loop over an `ArrayList` and compare every element to an `HashTable`. If the elements (string) are equal, I want to copy that in a new `HashTable` **neu**. Until here it goes well.
But I want, that if the word is already in the new `HashTable` **neu**, to not put it again and simple  add one count to the value which represents the frequency.
I suppose that the else-block is never reached in this code, because **test** output it's never displayed.
I know that until `contentEquals` it works well, there it returns me all words which are equal.

So: how can I verify if an String is already in a `HashTable`? I hope it's not duplicated, I have seen a lot of similar questions but didn't know how to use it correctly for my code.

```
Hashtable<String, Long> neu = new Hashtable<String, Long>();
ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
Hashtable<String, Long> count = new Hashtable<String, Long>();

// adding input

for (String s : count.keySet()) { 

    for (String x : words) {
            if (x.contentEquals(s)) {  
                if (!neu.containsKey(s)) {  
                    neu.put(s, (long) 1);
                } else { 
                    long p = neu.get(s); 
                    p = p + 1;
                    neu.put(s, p);
                    System.out.println("test");
                }
            }
        }
```

The Input is the following:
For count:

```
        try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                "griechenland_test.txt"));
        String str;

        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
            str = str.toLowerCase(); // convert to lower case
            String[] words = str.split("\\s+"); // split the line on
                                                // whitespace, would return
                                                // an array of words

            for (String word : words) {
                if (word.length() == 0) {
                    continue;
                }

                Long occurences = wordcount.get(word);

                if (occurences == null) {
                    occurences = (long) 1;
                } else {
                    occurences++;
                }

                count.put(word, occurences);
            }

        }
```

for words:

```
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("outagain.txt")); 
for (String line = br.readLine(); line != null; line = br.readLine()) {
        String h[] = line.split("   ");

        words.add(h[0].toString());

    }
```

Comment: Instead of guessing, use your debugger, or even add traces in the code, to **know** what is executed and what is not.

Comment: Why exactly do you use `contentEquals(Charsequence)` instead of `equals(Object)`?

Comment: If contentEquals in you code is correct , the code looks fine to me. May be the data you are using doesn't contains duplicates thats's why 'test' is not getting printed

Comment: I think `containsKey` is the answer to your question, and you're already using it.  So I don't understand what the question is about.

Comment: Please verify the content of your `words` and `count`. This should be the issue, because your code is working fine.

Comment: Are there any difference between `contentEquals` and `equals` ? I wasn't sure if it would work with equals because my input was String, so I thought that Charsequence would be the better choice

Comment: @ajb Notices my mistake already and deleted the comment. Could you remove your comment to prevent spam?

Comment: @user3057107; is there any part of the input where it eliminates duplicates? The "griechenland.txt" file is an normal article, where many words are repeated

Comment: Since `s` is a `String`, there's no difference.  A `String` is one type of `CharSequence`, and `contentEquals` works on other types of `CharSequence`s also, so there would be a difference if you were trying to compare a `String` to a `CharBuffer`, for example.  But when you compare two `String`s, they have the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could manage it! I supposed the fault was really the way from input, there where no duplicateds, for that reason the "else" was never reached! I just eliminate that condition and changed a bit the structure.
Thanks anyway all for your effort! :)

```
for (String x : hash.keySet()) {
        long neu = hash.get(x);
        for (String s : words) {
            if (x.equals(s)) {
                neuS.add(x);
                neuZ.add(neu);
                disc = disc + 1;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`containsKey()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#containsKey-java.lang.Object-) method to check if the given key is already in the hashtable.

```
static Hashtable<String, Long> map = new Hashtable<String, Long>();

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        map.put("test", 1l);

        System.out.println(map.containsKey("test")); // true
    }
```

For string comparison, either use the [`equals(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) or [`equalsIgnoreCase(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase-java.lang.String-) method.

So your code should look like this...

```
for (String s : count.keySet())
        {
            for (String x : words)
            {
                if (x.equals(s))
                    neu.put(s, neu.containsKey(s) ? neu.get(s) + 1 : 1l);
            }
        }
```

Please verify the content of your `words` and `count`. This should be the issue, because your code is working fine.

Comment: I already used the containsKey() method;
In `neu.containsKey(s))` , but thanks :D

Comment: Code works fine for me actually, I expected the contentEquals method to be the issue, it is not though. I rather think it is the content of the words and count variables.

Comment: and are there a difference between using equals or equalsIgnoreCase while using  Strings?

Comment: `equalsIgnoreCase()` - as the name suggests, is case insensitive. While comparing with `equals()`  is case sensitive, might be another cause of your issue, have you tried using `equalsIgnoreCase()`?

Comment: `equalsIgnoreCase()` doesn't change it.. Anyway, I think the problem is more with the if and else block,  because with `equals` it's working fine to detect the Strings which are equal.

Comment: Have you tried outputting all of the contents of your count and words list? I still think the problem is your data, not your code for comparison...